# Sort an array based on its sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sorting array based on inner-array key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530631/sorting-array-based-on-inner-array-key-value)

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 2 
    [name] => 4 
    [closed] => 
    [date] => 1319625994 
    [votes_up] => 0 
    [votes_down] => 0 
    [votes_pct_up] => 0 
    [votes_pct_down] => 0 
    [votes_balance] => 0 
    [votes_total] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [name] => 3 
    [closed] => 
    [date] => 1319625994 
    [votes_up] => 0 
    [votes_down] => 0 
    [votes_pct_up] => 0 
    [votes_pct_down] => 0 
    [votes_balance] => 0 
    [votes_total] => 0 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 4 
    [name] => 2 
    [closed] => 
    [date] => 1319625995 
    [votes_up] => 1 
    [votes_down] => 0 
    [votes_pct_up] => 100 
    [votes_pct_down] => 0 
    [votes_balance] => 1 
    [votes_total] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [name] => 1 
    [closed] => 
    [date] => 1319623450 
    [votes_up] => 2 
    [votes_down] => 0 
    [votes_pct_up] => 100 
    [votes_pct_down] => 0 
    [votes_balance] => 2 
    [votes_total] => 2 ) 
)
```

How do i sort these according to their `[votes_balance]` value?

Comment: this has been asked multiple times before. please use the search function before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [usort](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) function of PHP with something like this:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    if($a['id'] == $b['id']) return 0;
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: too complicated. just do `return $a['id'] - $b['id'];`.

Comment: i actually copied the example code from the php-docs.