# PHP nested array sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort the array below by show_name ASC and DESC, I tried many methods suggested in stackoverflow website but no luck so far, please help

$mainArray :

```
[78] => Array ( 
[main] => Array ( 
    [season_num] => 1 
    [episode_name] => Workflow 1 
    [episode_num] => 2 
    [show_id] => 15 
    [show_name] => Workflow Test 
    [type] => 
    [by_promo] => 
    [promo_type] => 
    [status] => I 
    [terminated] => ) 
    [approved] => Array ( 
    [asset] => on 
    [promo] => 
    [ingest] => 
    [review] => 
    [editing] => 
    [quality_control] => 
    [mcr] => 
    [archive] => ) 

    [notes] => Array ( 
        [promo] => 
        [ingest] => 
        [review] => 
        [editing] => 
        [quality_control] => 
        [mcr] => 
        [archive] => 
        [terminated] => )

    [file_path] => Array ( 
        [ingest] => 
        [editing] => ) 
        [priority] => 2 
        [work_type] => 0 
        [c_breaks] => 
        [editing_staff] => Array (
        [assigned_to] => 
        [assigned_from] => 21 ) 
        [asset] => Array ( 
        [date] => 1394828762 
        [user] => 26 
        [fullname] => User 2 ) 

    [ingest] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [promo] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [review] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [editing] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [quality_control] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [mcr] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [archive] => Array ( 
        [date] => 
        [user] => 
        [fullname] => ) 

    [status] => pending ) 


[79] => Array ( 
    [main] => Array ( 
        [season_num] => 2 [episode_name] => Doctor Who test [episode_num] => 4 [show_id] => 14 [show_name] => Doctor Who [type] => [by_promo] => [promo_type] => [status] => I [terminated] => ) [approved] => Array ( [asset] => on [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => ) [notes] => Array ( [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => [terminated] => ) [file_path] => Array ( [ingest] => [editing] => ) [priority] => 2 [work_type] => 0 [c_breaks] => [editing_staff] => Array ( [assigned_to] => [assigned_from] => 21 ) [asset] => Array ( [date] => 1394828776 [user] => 26 [fullname] => User 2 ) [ingest] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [promo] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [review] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [editing] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [quality_control] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [mcr] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [archive] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [status] => pending ) 

[80] => Array ( 
    [main] => Array ( 
        [season_num] => 4 [episode_name] => Spooks Test [episode_num] => 6 [show_id] => 11 [show_name] => Spooks [type] => [by_promo] => [promo_type] => [status] => I [terminated] => ) [approved] => Array ( [asset] => on [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => ) [notes] => Array ( [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => [terminated] => ) [file_path] => Array ( [ingest] => [editing] => ) [priority] => 2 [work_type] => 0 [c_breaks] => [editing_staff] => Array ( [assigned_to] => [assigned_from] => 21 ) [asset] => Array ( [date] => 1394828792 [user] => 26 [fullname] => User 2 ) [ingest] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [promo] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [review] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [editing] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [quality_control] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [mcr] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [archive] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [status] => pending ) 

[81] => Array ( 
    [main] => Array ( 
        [season_num] => 6 [episode_name] => Anc test [episode_num] => 8 [show_id] => 19 [show_name] => Anc Test [type] => [by_promo] => [promo_type] => [status] => I [terminated] => ) [approved] => Array ( [asset] => on [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => ) [notes] => Array ( [promo] => [ingest] => [review] => [editing] => [quality_control] => [mcr] => [archive] => [terminated] => ) [file_path] => Array ( [ingest] => [editing] => ) [priority] => 2 [work_type] => 0 [c_breaks] => [editing_staff] => Array ( [assigned_to] => [assigned_from] => 25 ) [asset] => Array ( [date] => 1394829087 [user] => 26 [fullname] => User 2 ) [ingest] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [promo] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [review] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [editing] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [quality_control] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [mcr] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [archive] => Array ( [date] => [user] => [fullname] => ) [status] => pending )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/1064767)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort an array by the inner key you can usually use the usort function.

In this case your code would look something like this.

***EDIT:*** Looks like you need another level. Try this.

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $b['main']['show_name'] < $a['main']['show_name']; });
```

To see this code in action, you can view here https://ideone.com/Mmv1gV

Keep in mind this actually modifies the value of your array in place.
See http://php.net/usort for more information.

Another potentially helpful link I found,
[sorting array based on inner-array key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530631/sorting-array-based-on-inner-array-key-value)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried many usort methods including yours, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ancogenli This works for me, I have edited my answer with a link to running PHP code.

Comment: In your example there is two nested Arrays, in my question there are 3 nested Arrays, this might be the issue, still not working for me

Comment: Your structure has two until the part you want to sort... `[78] => Array ( 
[main] => Array ( 
    [season_num] => 1 
    [episode_name] => Workflow 1 
    [episode_num] => 2 
    [show_id] => 15 
    [show_name] => Workflow Test ` .. Possibly you are implementing the sorting incorrectly? And even if that is the case, simply add another part to the sorting function for the next array?

Comment: Edited my answer, try that.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I found another solution but yours can handle DESC too. Thanks much again.